# SSH into multiple machines and run multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell-script

Writing a script to ssh into multiple machines and running multiple commands. However once the ssh is successful I get the following from each host without a single commands executing, the for loop works fine and I am able to ssh successfully into all the machines.

> Connection closed by host port 22

If I exclude the -tt flag in ssh I also get,

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

How do I get the following script to execute successfully on the machines.

Below is the script I am using

```bsh
for vm_ip in "${vm_ip_array[@]}"
do

ssh -tt -i {$key_pair} {$username}@${vm_ip} << HERE

[do multiple stuff here like update packages and other maintainence stuff (sudo commands)]

exit

HERE

done
```

Additional Info : I run a few export statements as well, will that be causing an issue?

Would it be recommended to have the multiple commands as a script on the individual machines? Updating the scripts this way is a nightmare though.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I recommend you use something like [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html) instead -- it's written for this exact type of use case.

Comment: It would help to know more about your multiple stuff, and where the export statements are. To troubleshoot this, I would start by only submitting parts of the script.adding more commands little by little and seeing from which point on the problem occurs.

Comment: if you want to ssh to multiple machines and run same commands on all of them, use pssh or ansible, pssh would probably be easier if you don't have ansible experience

Comment: Use pdsh - parallel distributed shell.